# ¿Se puede hacer DIE en conexion mysql? Para mostrar si conecto o no

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una web de testeo. PHP de conexión tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$conexion = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "contrasenia", "database");
if (!$conexion)
{
    printf("Error de conexión.", mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Quisiera que en vez de print no de más información, y que solo muestre:

**`Error de conexión`**

¿Hay alguna forma que yo pueda cambiar esto para que no sea prinf si no **`die "Error de conexion";`**?

Para ser un poco mas especifico necesito que este archivo exito_conexion_text.php muestre esto:

```
<?PHP
INCLUDE 'testeo.PHP';
?>
<html>
<h2>
EXITO al conectar CON EL SERVIDOR
</h2>
</html>
```

Si conecta SÓLO muestre esto al conectar pero si no que diga ERROR NO CONECTO.
Para ser mas claro es para testear si hay conexion o no.

Comment: por que en el método `mysqli_connect` usas el símbolo de `@` para precederlo?

Comment: @shadow sirve para evitar los errores y warning en PHP, si pones el arroba delante de una función, si ocurre un error simplemente no se mostrará.

Comment: eso lo se @sr_luis y eso lo preocupante de hecho, que aunque tenga errores no se los mostrará

Comment: @shadow tienes rázon ya que el como desarrollador no percibirá visualmente que haya un error, pero si le añade el método `mysqli_connect_error()` le debería de señalar el error, sin que le aparezca un letrero (demasiado visible) enseñandole el problema  y ocupandole parte del cuerpo de la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como alternativa, siempre puedes usar un try...catch. Sería algo así:

```
try {
    $conexion = @mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $bd);
    echo "Conexión efectuada.";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "La conexión no se pudo efectuar.";
    exit();
}
```

El objeto `$e`, que contiene la excepción si esta se ha producido, puedes usarlo durante tus pruebas para ver que es lo que ha fallado, o simplemente, dejarlo ahí, sin uso. No pide pan.

Bueno. Supongo que con "me da positivo" te refieres a que te sale el mensaje de "Conexión efectuada.". Dependiendo de la versión de PHP y la configuración, un error en mysqli_connect puede ser interpretado como un simple aviso, lo que, por sí solo, no lanza una excepción. Aunque he sacado este código de una web que tenía almacenada, es cierto que era bastante antigua.

Puedes hacer dos cosas:
1) Debajo de la línea de la conexión, forzar la excepción si no has conectado, así:

```
try {
    $conexion = @mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $bd);
    if (!$conexion) throw new Exception();
    echo "Conexión efectuada.";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "La conexión no se pudo efectuar.";
    exit();
}
```

Es una apaño, pero funciona para forzar la excepción, incluso en caso de que sólo se lance un warning.

La otra alternativa, que a mi me gusta más, es abandonar el uso prodedimental de la extensión mysqli y usar directamente PDO, así:

```
try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servidor.';dbname='.$bd.';charset=UTF8', $user, $pw);
    echo "Conexión efectuada.";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "La conexión no se pudo efectuar.";
    exit();
}
```

Trabajar las bases de datos con PDO te facilita las prestaciones de una BD y te permite escribir un código más limpio y mantenible.

Estas dos últimas opciones están probadas con PHP 7.1.3 y funcionando, con la configuración estándar que monta xampp por defecto. Espero que te sean útiles.

Comment: perdone amigo intente esa consulta pero me da positivo todo el tiempo podria verificarme como se hace por favor?

Comment: Te he ampliado la respuesta. Échale un vistazo, que te ayudará con esto.

Answer (score 1):

¡Claro! Sería así:

```
$conexion = @mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password, $bd ) 
                                     or die ("Error de conexion");
```

Se hace la conexión o para de ejecutarse la página y sólo mostrará el mensaje de error del `die`.

Otra forma es la siguiente, peró hace exactamente lo mismo:

```
<?php
$conexion = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'password', 'bd'); //conexión a la bd.

if (!$conexion) {  //condición en caso de que no se conecte la bd.
    die('Error de conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); //si no se conecta muestra "Error de conexión: " y el error en la conexión.
}
?>
```